# "TypeError: 'type' object is not subscriptable" when doing multiprocessing. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: python, pandas, performance, dataframe, multiprocessing

I try to "multi"-process the function `func`, but always get this error:

```
File "c:\...programs\python\python37\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 268, in map
    return self._map_async(func, iterable, mapstar, chunksize).get()

  File "c:\...\programs\python\python37\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 657, in get
    raise self._value

TypeError: 'type' object is not subscriptable
```

what am I doing wrong? every `job` is a dictionary, containing all the needed parameters for `func`

minimal reproducable sample:

```
import multiprocessing as mp,pandas as pd
def func(name, raw_df=pd.DataFrame, df={}, width=0):
    # 3. do some column operations. (actually theres more than just this operation)  
    seriesF =  raw_df[[name]].dropna()
    afterDropping_indices = seriesF.index.copy(deep=True) 
    list_ = list(raw_df[name])[width:]  
    df[name]=pd.Series(list_.copy(), index=afterDropping_indices[width:]) 
       
def preprocess_columns(raw_df ):
 
    # get all inputs.
    df, width = {}, 137 
    args = {"raw_df":raw_df, "df":df, 'width': width }  
    column_names = raw_df.columns

    # get input-dict for every single job.
    jobs=[]
    for i in range(len(column_names)):
        job = {"name":column_names[i]}
        job.update(args) 
        jobs.append(job) 

    # mutliprocessing
    pool = mp.Pool(len(column_names))  
    pool.map(func, jobs)    
    
    # create df from dict and reindex 
    df=pd.concat(df,axis=1) 
    df=df.reindex(df.index[::-1])
    return df 

if __name__=='__main__': 
    raw_df = pd.DataFrame({"A":[ 1.1 ]*100000, "B":[ 2.2 ]*100000, "C":[ 3.3 ]*100000}) 
    raw_df = preprocess_columns(raw_df )
```

EDIT: version where only column instead of raw_df is passed

```
import multiprocessing as mp,pandas as pd
def func(name, series, df, width):
    # 3. do some column operations. (actually theres more than just this operation)  
    seriesF =  series.dropna()
    afterDropping_indices = seriesF.index.copy(deep=True) 
    list_ = list(series)[width:]  
    df[name]=pd.Series(list_.copy(), index=afterDropping_indices[width:]) 
       
def preprocess_columns(raw_df ):
 
    df, width = {}, 137 
    args = {"df":df, 'width': width } 
     
    column_names = raw_df.columns
    jobs=[]
    for i in range(len(column_names)):
        job = {"name":column_names[i], "series":raw_df[column_names[i]]}
        job.update(args)  
        jobs.append(job)
    
    pool = mp.Pool(len(column_names))  
    pool.map(func, jobs)    
    
    # create df from dict and reindex 
    df=pd.concat(df,axis=1) 
    df=df.reindex(df.index[::-1])
    return df 

if __name__=='__main__': 
    raw_df = pd.DataFrame({"A":[ 1.1 ]*100000, "B":[ 2.2 ]*100000, "C":[ 3.3 ]*100000}) 
    raw_df = preprocess_columns(raw_df )
```

it results in:

```
TypeError: func() missing 3 required positional arguments: 'series', 'df', and 'width'
```

Comment: `raw_df=pd.DataFrame` doesn't make sense. Your workers need the actual dataframe, not `pd.DataFrame`. (Actually, they really only need the column they're going to work on, and you should change your code to pass just that column, to reduce inter-process communication overhead.)

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica please excuse, i forgot that i put those keyword there before posting the question. so unfortunately the keywords arent the cause of the error. Your suggestion on only passing the column sounds pretty nice, but isnt there a way to do it by only passing the name as the element on which parallelizing will happen?

Comment: The edited code would have produced a completely different error.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica would you be so kind, to rell me, what I am doing wrong? (edited again). 
to the comment before: `raw_df` was in the `args` dictionary

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution:
Summarized:

1. added expand_call() function (see below what it does).
2. iterating over output result and appending elements to a normal list.

Attention: this only deals with more than one threads.

```
import multiprocessing as mp,pandas as pd
def func(name, raw_df, df, width):
    # 3. do some column operations. (actually theres more than just this operation)  
    seriesF =  raw_df[name].dropna()
    afterDropping_indices = seriesF.index.copy(deep=True) 
    list_ = list(raw_df[name])[width:]  
    df[name]=pd.Series(list_.copy(), index=afterDropping_indices[width:])  
    df[name].name = name
    return df

def expandCall(kargs): 
    # Expand the arguments of a callback function, kargs[’func’] 
    func=kargs['func'] 
    del kargs['func']  
    out=func(**kargs)  
    return out
 
def preprocess_columns(raw_df ): 
    df, width = pd.DataFrame(), 137
    args = {"df":df, "raw_df":raw_df, 'width': width }
     
    column_names = raw_df.columns
    jobs=[]
    for i in range(len(column_names)):
        job = {"func":func,"name":column_names[i]}
        job.update(args)
        jobs.append(job)
    
    pool = mp.Pool(len(column_names))
    task=jobs[0]['func'].__name__
    outputs= pool.imap_unordered(expandCall, jobs)
    
    out = [];  
    for i,out_ in enumerate(outputs,1):
        out.append(out_)  
    pool.close(); pool.join() # this is needed to prevent memory leaks return out
      
    # create df from dict and reindex
    df=pd.concat(out,axis=1)  
    df=df.reindex(df.index[::-1]) 
    print(df)
    return df 

if __name__=='__main__': 
    raw_df = pd.DataFrame({"A":[ 1.1 ]*100000, "B":[ 2.2 ]*100000, "C":[ 3.3 ]*100000}) 
    raw_df = preprocess_columns(raw_df )
```